# UISearchDisplayController - Not getting result in uitableview

Tags: ios, delegates, uitableview, uisearchbar, uisearchdisplaycontroller

I am using `UISearchDisplayController` ,I am getting filtered data but this property is not active .

```
 tableView == self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView
```

so  I am not getting the proper result can anyone tell me what should I do ? I have done the coding programmatically .

Here is my .m file code

http://pastebin.com/ytMQ4CQi

Comment: Can you provide your code?

Comment: edited in the question

Answer (score 0):

That's a lot of code to go through, but...

I assume that you are trying to check for `tableView == self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView` within the `UITableViewDelegate` methods. But, in your setup code for the searchDisplayController you've missed the line `searchController.searchResultsDelegate = self;` You've set the `delegate` and `searchResultsDataSource`, but you forgot to set the `searchResultsDelegate`